# How to fill every seat number corresponding to the text button with a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, button

First of all, I'm a rookie in programming and I'm not English, I'm sorry if I had a mistake expressing myself :D

I'm doing a program that represents a booking system bus. I had created 64 buttons at Runtime with an array of buttons, but that isn't the problem.
The problem is to represent each text button corresponding to the number of seats of the bus. Here is my code:

```
var buttonArray = new Button[64];

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
   buttonArray[i] = new Button();
   buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(75, 23);
   buttonArray[i].Name = "button" + i;
   buttonArray[i].Text = "Seat " + i;
   buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(-50 + (i*100), 10);

   panel1.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);

   for (var j = 5; j <= 19; j++)
   {
        buttonArray[j] = new Button();
        buttonArray[j].Size = new Size(75, 23);
        buttonArray[j].Name = "button" + j;
        buttonArray[j].Text = "Seat " + j;
        buttonArray[j].Location = new Point(-50 + (i * 100), -105 + (j * 30));

        panel1.Controls.Add(buttonArray[j]);
    }
}
```

The result would be 64 buttons represented with 4 columns and 16 rows, for example:
[image: Example]

Comment: It looks like you are re-assigning the buttons 5-19 4 times. Why do you have a separate loop for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it: Just loop from zero to 63, and calculate the row and column on the fly. Then you set the button properties and add it to the panel. You can change the size of the seats by adjusting the `seatWidth` and `seatHeight` variables. Also note that I added a little extra space between the first two columns and the second two columns, because it looks like that's what you had in your diagram. You can adjust this with the `middleRowWidth` variable. You can also customize the distance between the seats by adjusting the `seatSpacing` value:

```
const int seatSpacing = 4;
const int middleRowWidth = 20;
const int seatWidth = 55;
const int seatHeight = 20;
panel1.Width = 4 * (seatWidth + seatSpacing) + seatSpacing + middleRowWidth;

var buttonSize = new Size(seatWidth, seatHeight);

for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    // Calculate the location for this seat
    int thisRow = i / 4;
    int thisColumn = i % 4;

    int seatTop = thisRow * (seatHeight + seatSpacing);
    int seatLeft = thisColumn * (seatWidth + seatSpacing);

    // Add some extra distance down the middle
    if (thisColumn >= 2) seatLeft += middleRowWidth;

    // Create a new button
    var thisButton = new Button
    {
        Size = buttonSize,
        Name = "button" + (i + 1),
        Text = "Seat " + (i + 1),
        Location = new Point(seatLeft, seatTop),
        Visible = true,
    };

    // Add it to the panel
    panel1.Controls.Add(thisButton);
}
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE**

After thinking about how to make this more generic, I thought about how some airplanes have their seats laid out. Some have two seats on each side, some have three, some have two on each side with a column of three down the middle. In order to accommodate different types of layouts, I modified the code slightly. Below code has customizable variables for your layout. The one below is for a `2-3-2` layout, where the numbers are the seat count and `-` are aisles. It also includes two "exit row" aisles running horizontally:

```
// Seating Layout
const int numberOfRows = 20;
const int numberOfColumns = 7;
const int numberOfSeats = numberOfRows * numberOfColumns;
var columnsToInsertAisleAfter = new List<int> {1, 4};
var rowsToInsertAisleAfter = new List<int> {6, 12};

// Seat sizing
const int seatWidth = 35;
const int seatHeight = 20;
const int seatSpacing = 4;
const int aisleWidth = 20;
var seatSize = new Size(seatWidth, seatHeight);

// Panel and form layout
panel1.Size = new Size(
    numberOfColumns * (seatWidth + seatSpacing) + seatSpacing +
    aisleWidth * columnsToInsertAisleAfter.Count,
    numberOfRows * (seatHeight + seatSpacing) + seatSpacing +
    aisleWidth * rowsToInsertAisleAfter.Count);

this.Size =
    new Size(panel1.Size.Width + (panel1.Left * 2),
        panel1.Size.Height + (panel1.Top * 2)) +
    new Size(this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width,
        this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height);

// Add seats to panel
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSeats; i++)
{
    // Calculate the location for this seat
    int thisRow = i / numberOfColumns;
    int thisColumn = i % numberOfColumns;

    int seatTop = thisRow * (seatHeight + seatSpacing);
    int seatLeft = thisColumn * (seatWidth + seatSpacing);

    // Add some extra distance for aisles
    var aislesBeforeThisColumn = 
        columnsToInsertAisleAfter.Count(col => col < thisColumn);
    seatLeft += aislesBeforeThisColumn * aisleWidth;

    var aislesBeforeThisRow = 
        rowsToInsertAisleAfter.Count(row => row < thisRow);
    seatTop += aislesBeforeThisRow * aisleWidth;

    // Add a new button to the panel
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Button
    {
        Size = seatSize,
        Name = "button" + (i + 1),
        Text = (i + 1).ToString(),
        Location = new Point(seatLeft, seatTop),
        Visible = true,
    });
}
```

Large Airplane Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want,

```
Point pt;
int y = 20;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   x = 20;
   for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
   {
      pt = new Point(x, y);
      Button btn = new Button() { Location = pt, Size = new Size(75, 23) };
      btn.Name = i.ToString() + j.ToString();
      btn.Text = string.Format("{0} {1:D2}", "Seat", i * 4 + j);
      panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
      x += 90;
    }
    y += 30;
 }
```